# SQL query needs to combine like rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a sql query as follows:

```
    SELECT
        EVENTTYPEDESCRIPTION,
        YEAR(EVENTSTARTDATE) as 'EVENTYEAR',
        COUNT(PARTICIPANTID) AS 'TOTALPARTICIPANTS'
    FROM WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS
    INNER JOIN WEBPROGRAMS
        ON WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS.PROGRAMCODE = WEBPROGRAMS.PROGRAMCODE
    INNER JOIN WEBEVENTS
        ON WEBPROGRAMS.PROGRAMID = WEBEVENTS.EVENTID
    INNER JOIN WEBEVENTTYPEDESCRIPTIONS
        ON WEBEVENTS.EVENTTYPE = WEBEVENTTYPEDESCRIPTIONS.EVENTTYPE
    WHERE WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS.ACCEPTED = 1
    GROUP BY EVENTTYPEDESCRIPTION, YEAR(EVENTSTARTDATE)
    ORDER BY EVENTTYPEDESCRIPTION, YEAR(EVENTSTARTDATE)
```

Which returns the following results:

```
EventTypeDescripti  Year    TotalParticipants
Affiliate Workshop  2004    96
Affiliate Workshop  2005    132
Affiliate Workshop  2006    94
Affiliate Workshop  2007    125
Affiliate Workshop  2008    121
Affiliate Workshop  2010    170
Affiliate Workshop  2011    1
IPAM Long Program   2000    59
IPAM Long Program   2001    203
IPAM Long Program   2002    94
IPAM Long Program   2003    182
IPAM Long Program   2004    147
IPAM Long Program   2005    123
IPAM Long Program   2006    99
IPAM Long Program   2007    116
IPAM Long Program   2008    98
IPAM Long Program   2009    127
IPAM Long Program   2010    147
IPAM Long Program   2011    105
IPAM Long Program   2012    14
IPAM Reunion Conference 2002    108
IPAM Reunion Conference 2003    100
IPAM Reunion Conference 2004    98
IPAM Reunion Conference 2005    68
```

My question is how do I reconstruct the query to show each EventTypeDescription condensed into one line and show each year as a column with its respective count

Example:

```
Description            Year            Year           etc...
Affiliate Workshop     96              132            ....
```

Comment: You should work on limiting the number of uppercase letters you have in a table or column name

Comment: Which DBMS?  It is likely to matter...

Comment: Its SQL, just like I stated in the title and tags

Comment: Why does the uppercase lettering matter? This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @mattgcon We know its SQL, but what database engine are you using?, Oracle?, MySql?, SQL Server?.....etc

Comment: SQL Server, apologies I thought it was just implied

Comment: Is it for displaying in a website ? excel table ? csv export? Maybe just using post treatment (PHP, or any other language)on this data set may do the trick.

Comment: @mattgcon It only matters because people have to read your question ANDITSDIFFICULTTOREADSTUFFTHATLOOKSLIKETHIS

Comment: Joe, apologies, i thought you meant in my actual stored procedures here at work, its a company policy so I have to follow it. I will make sure to change to lower case when posting next time

Comment: This is going into a chart actually line chart within a windows app

Comment: @mattgcon You want the Years to be columns, right?, are those years dynamic?, or are they always the same?

Comment: The line chart require one row per group with x coor(years) and y coor(count)

Comment: Lamak, yes the years need to be the columns and they are dynamic

Comment: Joe, I apologize for being testy in the past I have asked questions and have had people answer something or say something that wasnt even related to what I asked.

Comment: @mattgcon Don't worry about it. I just want to make sure people can read the question so you can get a solution

Comment: Could I take care of this issue using C# and a class method to combine the rows?

Comment: You can use a query to list the descriptions, a query to list all the existing years and then use your queries to construct your table in c#. But i guess you can also do it in a stored procedure.

Comment: **SQL** = Structured Query Language - almost all serious relational DB systems use SQL as their query language; just mentioning "SQL" doesn't imply any vendor or system at all.... (a very common "misconception", it seems .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your efforts. I am going to remember the PIVOT example once our database is upgraded to 2008. For now since we are using SQL Server 2000 I decided to do the pivot within my c# code.

It is actually better this way forme anyway, since the way Icreaetd it I can pass in any select query result and it will pivot it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since I don't know from what table each column of your result comes, then I'm gonna have to use a temp table for this. Then, you are gonna need dynamic sql, so take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) first. Then, try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Years NVARCHAR(MAX), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Years = ''

SELECT eventtypedescription, 
       YEAR(eventstartdate) AS 'EVENTYEAR', 
       COUNT(participantid) AS 'TOTALPARTICIPANTS' 
INTO #Results
FROM   webprogramparticipants 
INNER JOIN webprograms 
 ON webprogramparticipants.programcode = webprograms.programcode 
INNER JOIN webevents 
 ON webprograms.programid = webevents.eventid 
INNER JOIN webeventtypedescriptions 
 ON webevents.eventtype = webeventtypedescriptions.eventtype 
WHERE  webprogramparticipants.accepted = 1 
GROUP  BY eventtypedescription, YEAR(eventstartdate) 


SELECT @Years = @Years + '[Year ' + CAST(EVENTYEAR AS VARCHAR) +'],'
FROM #Results
GROUP BY EVENTYEAR
ORDER BY EVENTYEAR

SET @Years = LEFT(@Years,LEN(@Years)-1)

SET @Query = '
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT eventtypedescription, TOTALPARTICIPANTS, ''Year ''+CAST(EVENTYEAR AS VARCHAR) Years
        FROM #Results) T
PIVOT(SUM(TOTALPARTICIPANTS) FOR Years IN ('+@Years+')) AS PT'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: This is basically what I was going to provide.

Comment: The declare @years NVARCHAR(MAX) causes an error saying incorrect syntax near 'MAX'

Comment: Put a semicolon after that line

Comment: @mattgcon - That's weird, if I run that query with a test table, it works fine, maybe the `ORDER BY` clause?, I edited my answer so you can try again

Comment: I even copied your updated code and tested and still getting the same error

Comment: @mattgcon - I changed the order of the declaring of the variables, so you can tell if the error is the same as before

Comment: It has to do with the MAX, when I took those out it ran, I didnt see the results but it did run without erros

Comment: This may be because I am using SQL 2008 R2 maybe?

Comment: @mattgcon - well, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is valid on SQL Server 2008, but you can change it for `NVARCHAR(4000)` and try. Now, you said that it returns no results, so, can yo show me a PRINT of the variables @years and @query?

Comment: here is the @years variable: [Year 2000],[Year 2001],[Year 2002],[Year 2003],[Year 2004],[Year 2005],[Year 2006],[Year 2007],[Year 2008],[Year 2009],[Year 2010],[Year 2011],[Year 2012]

Comment: here is the @query variable (which is causing an error at PIVOT): SELECT * FROM (  SELECT eventtypedescription, TOTALPARTICIPANTS, 
'Year '+CAST(EVENTYEAR AS VARCHAR) Years         FROM #Results) T PIVOT(SUM(TOTALPARTICIPANTS) FOR Years IN ([Year 2000],[Year 2001],[Year 2002],[Year 2003],[Year 2004],[Year 2005],[Year 2006],[Year 2007],[Year 2008],[Year 2009],[Year 2010],[Year 2011],[Year 2012])) AS PT

Comment: Why would I be getting an Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT' everything looks good though

Comment: @Lamak, Im sorry i know why the PIVOT isnt working, I was given the wrong information in regards to the SQL Server version (it is 2000) not 2008 like I was told.

Comment: @mattgcon - Then that's the reason why it also gave you an error with `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a cursor to generate a string of which rows you'll need
2. Use a pivot to [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) the data on the EventTypeDescription column. Example on its way.

Comment: Joe this is SQL Server 2008 R2, Pivots dont look like they will work because the Years are dynamic

Comment: Joe it is a SQL Server 2000 instance that I am working off of, wrong info given to me. We are upgrading to 2008 R2 soon I know that

Comment: In that case you cannot use PIVOT, you must use Cursors to pivot the data manually. Cursors are basically just loops